# Dynamic label change on button click

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the label text with the code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttontobepressed(_sender: Any)
    {
       displayMessage.text?="button pressed"  
    }

    @IBOutlet  weak var displayMessage: UILabel!
```

when I try running it, it gives me an exception:

> $ ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException$

Full log:

> **2017-06-10 12:07:14.672 blabby[4334:781388] -[blabby.ViewController buttontobepressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf54fe0 2017-06-10 12:07:14.679 blabby[4334:781388] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[blabby.ViewController buttontobepressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf54fe0' libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) **

Comment: Remove the `?` after the `text` property write it like `displayMessage.text = "button pressed"`

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException'  is the error message show ...an uncaught exception.

Comment: Is your label outlet connected ? also add full error

Comment: **2017-06-10 12:07:14.672 blabby[4334:781388] -[blabby.ViewController buttontobepressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf54fe0
2017-06-10 12:07:14.679 blabby[4334:781388] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[blabby.ViewController buttontobepressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf54fe0'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) **

Comment: add the space between `_` and `sender` like `buttontobepressed(_ sender: Any)`

Comment: it worked nirav, being the noob im ..removing the space helped

Comment: Glad it works for you

Comment: thanks i meant adding the space. sorry

Comment: Yes I get that :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using `Any` class inside a action method is **to check the appropriate class always** when performing action, see below.

```
@IBAction func buttontobepressed(_ sender: Any){

    // checking if sender is as object of UIButton class
    if sender is UIButton{
        self.displayMessage.text = "button pressed"    
    }
}
```

**Note:** for proper use of any UI component including `UILabel` inside your programm you must connect its `IBOutlet` using storyboard after declare, otherwise you will get the runtime error.

Comment: @Mozahler thank you for your point, but we consider some obvious prior knowledge to op.